# how to hide pages from unregistered users

Tags: php, web

I want to hide certain pages on my navigation bar for users that are not registered, not to see those certain pages.

If a user is not registered, no access will be given on some pages.
Meaning if you are not a registered member you will be limited to seeing some pages. Otherwise if you a member you have access to all the pages.

I'm using PHP.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: `if ($registered) { show stuff }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have accomplish this by adding the following code

```
if ($userid == "") {
    Header("Location: index.php");
    die();
}
```

This worked like a charm.

Comment: Are you using some framework that supplies $userid? If not, this is entirely specific to your application, and not really useful to the SO community.

Comment: I'm not using a framework. `$userid` is a variable I used throughout the application when user login.

Comment: Then this question and answer are of no use to the community and should probably be removed.

Comment: If the `$userid` was supplied by framework would this question be of a use to the community? The `$userid` I created myself to track when users login.

Comment: If it was supplied by a framework, it would be useful to people using that framework. As it stands, it is useful to you alone.

Comment: If the `$userid` was supplied by framework would this question be of a use to the community? The `$userid` I created myself to track when users login.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following: Create a field in user_on = true session when the user is logged in.

And in the Menu list check if this field exists in the session so if any it shows the menu item .

Ex:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_on'])) {
   echo '<a href="http:://...">Link</a>';
}
```

Comment: This helped a lot. Thanks